# Why is indexOf() not working inside of a .map() using google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to auto assign categories from a bank statement. I've mapped out 10 months worth of banking descriptions to categories, however some descriptions changed based on the date. So my solution was to check it for pertinent information using indexOf() like so.

```
var descriptions = {
  //...key value pairs
  "Walgreens #12345   London   UK": "Medical Needs" //Example of repeating description
  "Hulu": "Subscriptions", // Example of description that needs to find a substring with indexOf()
  //...more key value pairs
}

function assignCategory(range) {
  return range.map(function (desc) {
    if (descriptions[desc]) {
      return descriptions[desc];
    }
    else if (desc.indexOf("Hulu") !== -1) { //Hulu changes based on the date but always has hulu in it.
      return descriptions["Hulu"]; //Look up the value to the associated key and add it to the array.
    }
    else {
      return "UNKNOWN";
    }
  });
}
```

If I call the indexOf() function outside of the .map() it works flawlessly, and from everything that I can see it should work inside .map(), barring some strange google script editor behind the scenes stuff or javascript stuff. Anyone able to educate me?

**Edit per @Tanaike

```
Date       No.  Description                  Debit       Credit     Category
9/3/2019        Purchase Description One     $ 40.00                Eating Out
9/3/2019        Purchase Description Two     $ 100.00               Grocery
9/3/2019        Purchase Description Three   $ 2.69                 Misc
```

Where each heading corresponds with a column in a spreadsheet:

- A - Date
- B - No.
- C - Description
- D - Debit
- E - Credit
- F - Category

I could provide you with a script, but it is quite literally nothing more that what I already posted. A description dictionary of key/value pairs and one function 'assignCategory(range).

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail information of `indexOf() not working inside of a .map()`? And can you provide the script and the sample values of `range` for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Can you detail an example value of the `range` argument?

Comment: @Tanaike Updated with a bit more information. There isn't really much else to show as far as the script is concerned though.

Comment: How are you calling the method?

Comment: @tehhowch So in line with the example above. In cell F2 the category column, I would put =assignCategory(C2:C4) and the resulting array would be all my categories right where they need to be, leaving the only unknowns something that isn't in the descriptions dictionary. However, anything that is using the indexOf() statement is also getting a value of unknown rather than their assigned category.

Comment: I know it seems I'm keeping things vague, but it is my bank statements. If you need more detailed actual examples I'll try to pull an actual data set that doesn't reveal much about me, my location, etc....

Comment: And what "isn't working" about `indexOf`? Error message? Wrong value returned? Note that `desc` is actually an array with a single element...

Comment: @tehhowch As far as what isn't working, it's the `if (desc.indexOf("Hulu") !== -1)` inside the callback of the .map function. That exact code works outside of the callback, but as you said since its an array element that is being passed it may not be checking it against the description, but something else instead... That all being said, the main reason I chose use .map() is so that I wouldn't have to keep up with an iterator. Is there a way to access what iteration the .map() callback is receiving?

Comment: "that exact code" cannot possibly work outside the `map` callback as `desc` would be `undefined` and the code would correctly throw a TypeError. The `Array#indexOf` method uses SameValueZero equality checking, so unless one of its elements contains only the exact text "Hulu" will you have a match. Probably your intent is to check the presence of the string anywhere within any of the array *elements*